# Facebook Insights not working with domain that has an homepage redirect?

Tags: facebook-insights

I have a domain that 301 redirects itself from http://www.domainname.com to http://www.domainname.com/subfolder/

The Facebook meta property tag is present on every page of the subfolder and it was recognized by Facebook when I added it in my Insights Dashboard. However, insights data are not showing for anything -- not the website, the like button or the comment box.

Any advice? Can it be related to the fact that the domain homepage redirects istself to a subfolder?

Answer (score 1):

If [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) can't read the tags, you can't claim the domain. Check you're exempting the Facebook crawler from your redirect, or else it won't be able to access your meta tags.

Comment: I was able to claim the domain but still Facebook Insights doesn't show any data. I've tried to check the Facebook Debug Tool and it is able to retrieve the meta property tag:

<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxxxxxxxxx" />

Comment: Any data since when? most statistics take 2 days to generate